# PHP Function Dependent on presence of MySQL data entry

Tags: php, mysql, null, include

I code a weekly trivia program for one of my clients through facebook.

I have a bit of code commented out where we display the winner when we need to. Currently I just remove the comment brackets and update when it's time to display. I'm trying to make this so someone non-savvy can handle updates so I've moved my code into an include:

winner-display.php

I am trying to write a function so that if the winner is set in MySQL, it includes the file in-line, and if the winner field is empty in the database, it does not.

Here is what I have so far, any ideas?

```
<?php 
$target="3";
$myDataID = mysql_query("SELECT topic_desc from ref_links WHERE ref_categories_id = '$target' AND topic_name = '$property'", $connectID); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($myDataID)) {
    $displayvalue = $row ['topic_desc'];
}
if ( $displayvalue != 'null') {
    include('../includes/winner-display.php');
} else {
}
?>
```

Ok, thanks for helping guys, got it to work as:

```
<?php 
$target="3";
$myDataID = mysql_query("SELECT topic_desc from ref_links WHERE ref_categories_id = '$target' AND topic_name = '$property'", $connectID); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($myDataID)) {
    foreach ($row as $field) {
        if ($field != null) {
            include('../includes/winner-display.php');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if putting an include in an if statement like that works, but if it does, then you probably just want to remove the quotes from around 'null'.

Comment: did this work for you? do you have a problem? have you tested it? any errors?

Comment: Ben - PHP includes are execution-time. When an include statement is encountered while executing the file, the included file is parsed there and then, and execution moves to the top of the included file. So you can put an include statement wherever you want.

Comment: Zak - I tried it with the quotes removed around null and I do get an error: 'Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/kevin/Sites/trivia/gdwr/index.php on line 31'....... line 31 is the 'while' line

Comment: Of course, you could just put the operations performed in `winner-display.php` into a function and call the function if your condition is met.

Comment: Winner display is actually just a bunch of HTML code that creates an overlay with a few includes to pull the winner/prize from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely put an include within an if.  That solution that you posted should work as you would like it to, although I personally would have used a function instead of a completely separate file to include (although that is personal preference).

All you have to do to make it work is remove the quotes around 'null'.

```
<?php 
$target="3";
$myDataID = mysql_query("SELECT topic_desc from ref_links WHERE ref_categories_id = $target' AND topic_name = '$property'", $connectID); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($myDataID)) {
    $displayvalue = $row ['topic_desc'];
}
if ( $displayvalue != null) {
    include('../includes/winner-display.php');
}
?>
```

Keep in mind that if your query returns more than one row, only the last row will be retained.  I don't know if that is the functionality you want (in which case, there are some changes you could make, just ask me to edit my answer), but I didn't change that.

Comment: I didn't realize that about the query retaining only the last row, but in this case it should be okay. There is only one row in the database that will contain both the ref_categories_id and topic_name I am searching for. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, actually I just tried this and I get an error:  
'Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/kevin/Sites/trivia/gdwr/index.php on line 31'.......  
  
line 31 is the 'while' line